# How to find who last changed a file with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I need the user who last changed/committed a file in our GIT repository.

The project consists of many subfolders, and the master branch has many merged commits.

I tried :

```
File gitWorkDir = new File("D:/gitfolder/");
Git git = Git.open(gitWorkDir);
RevCommit latestCommit;
String path = "test.txt";
try( RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( git.getRepository() ) ) {
    Ref headRef = git.getRepository().exactRef( Constants.HEAD );
    RevCommit headCommit = revWalk.parseCommit( headRef.getObjectId());
    revWalk.markStart( headCommit );
    revWalk.sort( RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC );
    TreeFilter filter = AndTreeFilter.create( PathFilter.create( path ), TreeFilter.ANY_DIFF );
    revWalk.setTreeFilter(filter);
    latestCommit = revWalk.next();
    git.close();
}
```

the Repository and HEAD commit are there, but `latestCommit` is always null.

Do I have to define the whole path to my file? 
Is it a problem that the master branch is so "branched out" so maybe the commit cannot be found, or what else could be the problem?

Comment: Do you want to know the author who last changed a **specific** file?

Comment: Yes, I have a list of about 500 files, and need the information for each file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git I would use `git log --follow path/to/your/file`. It gives you the **full git history of a specific file** (including commit author even if the file name was changed or file was moved to another folder).

For doing this with JGit check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471836/how-to-git-log-follow-path-in-jgit-to-retrieve-the-full-history-includi).

Espacially this part should be intresting (taken from above answer):

```
 /**
 * Returns the result of a git log --follow -- < path >
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws MissingObjectException
 * @throws GitAPIException
 */
public ArrayList<RevCommit> call() throws IOException, MissingObjectException, GitAPIException {
    ArrayList<RevCommit> commits = new ArrayList<RevCommit>();
    git = new Git(repository);
    RevCommit start = null;
    do {
        Iterable<RevCommit> log = git.log().addPath(path).call();
        for (RevCommit commit : log) {
            if (commits.contains(commit)) {
                start = null;
            } else {
                start = commit;
                commits.add(commit);
            }
        }
        if (start == null) return commits;
    }
    while ((path = getRenamedPath( start)) != null);

    return commits;
}
```