# How to get a list of folders and files in particular commit id with jgit

Tags: java, spring, git, git-branch, jgit

I have seen a lot of tutorials but I haven't found any code for getting all the files and folders in a particular commit id. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit)

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727610/how-to-get-the-list-of-files-as-a-part-of-commit-in-jgit. Also note that git does not bother itself about folders but only files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only bd61ad98
```

Comment: I want to  Jgit code but not GitHub commands

Comment: I want to get list of folders and files with commit id by using java code using jgit. I tried a lot of tutorials but it is not working. Please help me, thanks in advance.