# How to list commits in JGit with filepath

Tags: jgit, git-log

I want to list the commits of a local Git repository in Java. So I am using below code to do so:

```java
Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();
```

But I also need the path of every file that was committed and listed in git log.

Comment: For each commit in `commits` you can list the files as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590039/how-to-get-the-file-list-for-a-commit-with-jgit

Comment: I am getting IncorrectObjectTypeException on line `treeWalk.reset(rev.getId());` in below code.  `Iterable<RevCommit> logs = git.log().call(); </br> for (RevCommit rev : logs) { </br> `

Comment: What is `rev`? Please edit your question to include the complete snippet that you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding [`IncorrectObjectTypeException`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/errors/class-use/IncorrectObjectTypeException.html), you do have the [TreeWalk.reset()](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/treewalk/TreeWalk.html#reset(org.eclipse.jgit.lib.AnyObjectId)) throwing that exception because, from the Javadoc:

> **the given object id does not denote a tree**, but instead names some other non-tree type of object. Note that commits are not trees, even if they are sometimes called a "tree-ish".

See [those examples of `TreeWalk.reset`](http://www.massapi.com/method/org/eclipse/jgit/treewalk/TreeWalk.reset-5.html) to see how to access the tree from a given commit. Like `rev.getTree()`.

Comment: examples link helped me. Thanks

Comment: @RujutaS Great! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Solution worked for me:

```
ObjectReader or = repository.newObjectReader();
        RevWalk rw = new RevWalk(or);
        TreeWalk tw = new TreeWalk(or);
          tw.setFilter(TreeFilter.ANY_DIFF);
          tw.setRecursive(true);
          ObjectId start = repository.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
          startId = or.abbreviate(start);
          rw.markStart(rw.parseCommit(start));

          for(;;){
          RevCommit c = rw.next();
          if (c == null){
              break;
          }
          if (c.getParentCount() != 1){
              continue;
          }
          RevCommit p = c.getParent(0);
            rw.parseHeaders(p);
            tw.reset(p.getTree(), c.getTree());
            while (tw.next()) {
                System.out.println(tw.getPathString()+" id: "+c.getId());
            }
          }
```